# C# уведомление во время выполнения методов в c#. Возможно ли такое?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне стало интересно. У меня, например, есть программа с графическим интерфейсом на WPF. При каждом выполнении методов (например после нажатия кнопки, когда данные берутся из бд) программа выполняет инструкции, но в это время (если это правильно сказано) блокируется поток и складывается ощущение что программа "зависает". Таких методов много и на каждый писать дополнительный метод, который открывает поток, чтобы показать уведомление по типу "подождите..." мне показалось затратным.

Так вот собственно вопрос: Есть ли такая "функция", которая при каждом таком "зависании" выполняет вывод на экран сообщения "Подождите..." и убирает его по окончанию работы метода?

Извините, если непонятно объяснила или если этот вопрос глуп.

Comment: Можно, конечно, сделать перехват (interception), написать декораторы... Но лучше ваши методы работы с БД сделать асинхронными.

Comment: Никогда в потоке окна на пихайте функции которые могут выполняться продолжительное время. Используйте для этого асинхронный поток с уведомлениями.

Comment: Если вы используете ADO.NET для работы с БД, то надо сделать рефакторинг на использование асинхронных вариантов: открывать содениение с БД с помощью `OpenAsync()`, задействовать `ExecuteReaderAsync()` вместо `ExecuteReader()` и т.п., там у всех синхронных есть асинхронные собратья.

Answer (score 1):

В XAML добавить вот такую форму, которая будет служить экраном загрузки:

```
<Grid Name="ProcessScreen" Visibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DockPanel Background="Black" Opacity="0.9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3"></DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="Process2TB" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Выполняется формирование запроса, пожалуйста подождите!" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="ProcessTB" Text="Процесс" Height="18" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="White" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ></TextBlock>
                <ProgressBar Name="ProcessPB" Background="#FF686868"  Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Maximum="100" Foreground="#FF003AFF" BorderBrush="#FF007ACC"/>
            </Grid>
```

В C# добавьте это (функция отображения и запуска экрана):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                FunctionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(VashZapros));
                FunctionThread .Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                FunctionThread .Start();
            }

        public void VashZapros()
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ProcessScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ProcessPB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ProcessTB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ProcessTB.Text = "Загрузка запроса";
            });

//ТУТ ВАШ КОД, который делает запросы и тд
//или напишите хендлер, который будет отлавливать окончания работы вашего запроса
//и соответсвенно закрывать экран загрузки, но можно и без него, просто вставлять 
//такую конструкцию в каждый запрос, быстро и не так много 

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ProcessPB.Value = ProcessPB.Maximum;
                ProcessPB.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                ProcessTB.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                ProcessScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            });
         }
```

P.S. у меня лично было реализованно таким образом, надеюсь этот метод подойдет и вам.
С уважением и удачи.

Comment: Вот так просто рубим в `Button_Click()`, `new Thread()` . Сегодня последний день апреля года 2020  люди давно применяют MVVM, `ICommand` и `async/await` всякие.

Comment: Дельное замечание. сложно не согласиться, что у вас решение более прогрессивное, та прога, от куда я брал свой код, была написана мною уже года 2 назад, но от того актуальности и работоспособности она не потеряла, конечно же можно ее загрейдить асинками всякими и задать поток другим путем.

Comment: Хорошее объяснение, но я имела в виду другое. Есть ли какая-то метка что ли, когда начинается и заканчивается метод и на каждое "зависание" где-то прописать один метод, который во время "зависания" будет автоматически вызываться.(В поисках самых простых решений)

Comment: Мне в голову не приходят какие то прям совсем готовые решения, я лично пользовался таким способом, единственное что, можно погуглить что такое EventHendler и присобачить его в функцию, но там надо авторски поработать)))

Comment: @AB - нет такой метки. Но довольно близко к тому, что вы хотите - _перехват_. Кратко не объяснить. Тем более я почти уверен, что у вас весь код в баттон-кликах... Читайте книгу Марка Симанна Dependency Injection in .NET - после обеспечения слабой связанности архитектуры можно будет применить те самые интерсепторы-перехватчики. Ну и книгу Metaprogramming in .NET можете полистать. В ней есть впечатляющие (на первый взгляд) примеры, когда навешивание атрибута (sic! как вы и хотели) на методы позволяет творить чудеса (запускать их в другом потоке и т. п.) Но для этого, опять же, нужно менять код.

Comment: Почитав такие комменты можно и из ООП перейти АОП =)

Comment: Да, автору, судя по всему, следует познакомиться с АОП. Я, кстати, имел в виду книгу AOP in .NET, но и Metaprogramming пригодится.